# gnome-screenshot command --display option doesn't work

Tags: gnome-screenshot

I have multiple monitors and would like to take snapshot on only one of them, but the `gnome-screenshot --display=Monitor_ID` doesn't work.

Here is output of `xrandr --query`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-7 connected 1280x1024+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 370mm x 300mm
   1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02* 
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Here is output of `gnome-screenshot --display=DP-3`

```
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: DP-3

(gnome-screenshot:17493): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: DP-3
```

Do I need to do something else to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it's expecting an X display designator like `--display=:2`

Comment: What do you mean? should I use following command instead?  "gnome-screenshot --display=DP-3:2"

Comment: Not quite - try just the `:n` part (as obtained for example from `xdpyinfo | grep display`) - what the xrandr man page refers to as the "X screen abstraction"